# Node.js: How to import test files in custom test runner

Tags: node.js

I'm trying to create my own custom testing framework for learning purpose. Test files are written in following way

```
import { somemethod } from './some/module'

test(/I click on a button)/, () => {
  browser.get("someSelector").should("have.text",somemethod());
});
```

I user `require(file)` to load test files. But it throw error `SyntaxError: Unexpected token {`
 for import statement in test file. I'm using node js version 11.15.

If I switch to node v13.14 and define `"type": "module"` in my package.json then it doesn't let me use `require(file)` to load a test file or any module in my package.

How can I import tests files considering the user may be importing the modules using `import` or `require`?

Comment: Does it work with the commonjs approach? ```const { somemethod } = require('./some/module')``` ?

Comment: I can try that but then it'll be like forcing the users to adopt commonjs approach only.

Comment: limiting to test my project only, commonjs approach work. But again there should not be any module imported in test file which use `export` statement :(

Comment: I was suggesting a basic commonjs approach to understand if you have other problem underneath. If that works we can start safely to make it work using es6 imports.

Comment: Ok, so if that works I'll try to write a possible way to debug it

Answer (score 0):

This answer is very empirical...
Considering that it works using canonical commonjs approach you can try to debug it with newer version of NODE (currently I would use 14). For it, I would suggest you to use a node version manager like NVM so you can switch between node version easily and test that accordling seeing differences between various node installations.
Make a minimal project with npm init with a single dependency, save your index with the `.mjs` extension and try an import the above dependency. If you are be able to import that dependency with that minimal environment you can blame either your previous node or your configuration or both of them.
At the moment you should only create a small 2 files project to reproduce the problem. It seems your current node does not consider the `"type": "module"` configuration and runs everything in its classic way.

Regarding your comments....

As far as I know `import` can be used even in your code, not just at the beginning:

```js
(async () => {
  if (somethingIsTrue) {
    // import module for side effects
    await import('/modules/my-module.js');
  }
})();
```

from https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/import

Additionally you can try Webpack with a configuration like:

```js
// webpack.config.js
const nodeExternals = require('webpack-node-externals');

module.exports = {
    mode: 'production',
    target: 'node',
    externals: [nodeExternals()],
    entry: {
        'build/output': './src/index.js'
    },
    output: {
        path: __dirname,
        filename: '[name].bundle.js',
        libraryTarget: 'commonjs2'
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
            {
                test: /\.js$/,
                use: {
                    loader: 'babel-loader',
                    options: {
                        presets: [
                            ['env', {
                                'targets': {
                                    'node': 'current'
                                }
                            }]
                        ]
                    }
                }
            }]
    }
};
```

With `NodeExternals` you don't put your node dependencies in the bundle but only your own code. You refer to node_modules for the rest. You might not want that.

Comment: I will need to import the files somewhere in between the code `files.forEach(fileName => require(fileName));`. So I can't use use with nodev13+, I'll have to use `import` only. But `import` need to be in starting of the file.

Comment: In addition, syntax like `classMethod = function () {}` or `classMethod = () => {}` are not supported. They need to be `classMethod() {}`. So I feel I need to first transpile the project using some babel or webpack. I don't know how. and then I can import it.

Comment: I tried `require-dir` package, cucumber js package. All gives the same error. I believe I require some additional config. Some suggested to use `@babel/core` & `@babel/register`. But I'm not sure if I'm using them correctly

Comment: I believe the webpack solution you're suggesting is for source folder/project

Comment: You can specify as many entry points as you want, even with tests. If your purpose is testing your library and release it, that can be a solution.

Comment: I get `Error: Not supported` for import statement. Thanks for your time. But I think I need to investigate how existing testing libraries work. Like mocha, jesmine, or jest

Comment: As you wish, but if a new version of babel doesn't support it I don't think you can expect that what you are doing can work in an "older" node.js instance.

Comment: I have created this sample repo to try this: https://github.com/amitguptagwl/JSTestFramework